# Rejected by the App-store due to in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I recently uploaded an application that got rejected by Apple due to in-app purchases, the application had a login page before the in-app purchase, which is not allowed.

Now I want to delete the in-app purchase from the application, all the code has been commented out, but how do I de-activate the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect.

I know there is a switch called "Cleared for Sale" in the Manage In-App Purchase section of iTunes connect, but my question is if that is enough to just set that switch to No.

Do that de-activate any in-app purchase references for the application and will the app be reviewed without in-app purchase?

Or is there any other things I must consider to get the application through the review without in-app purchase.

This is message from Apple that triggered the rejection:

> 17.2 We found that your app requires customers to register with personal information to access non-account-based features, which is
>   not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically,
>   users must register to purchase additional content.  Apps cannot
>   require user registration prior to allowing access to app features and
>   content  that are not associated specifically to the user. User
>   registration that requires the  sharing of personal information must
>   be optional or tied to account-specific   functionality. Additionally,
>   the requested information must be relevant to the features.

Comment: Does your app requires user to login/register for the first time to use the app? is it compulsory process to access your app?

Comment: This rejection is nothing to do with in app purchase... I had same rejection...

Comment: Why you want `use-info` when you get `user-money` !!? :)

Comment: @vinaybagale yes, the user requires it.

Comment: and @vinaybagale this is just an update, required login has always been a part of the application.

Comment: You can provide demo user access or provide at least some basic functionality of the app.

Comment: @vinaybagale Thanks for your response, but why? The application is almost the same as the one on the App-store already. This is just bugfixes and some minor UI tweaks.

Comment: Yes, but this is as per apple guidelines and solution which worked out for me. Even i had apps with same login mechanism initially.

Comment: You should provide some demo account mechanism to at least allow user to access some functionality of your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I want to delete the in-app purchase from the application, all the code has been commented out

Removing the in-app purchase access point (button action etc) from the application code is adequate Sounds like you have that covered.

> how do I de-activate the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect.

It is not necessary once the code is removed. However, to remove In-App purchased do the following.

1. Log into iTunes Connect
2. Go to your app's "Manage In-App Purchases"
3. Select an in-app purchase row
4. Select the "Delete" button found in the top left corner of the editing in app purchase screen
5. Confirm and repeat for others you wish to delete

Re-submit and good luck!

Comment: I was going to answer this, I had to remove the in-app purchase to fix this problem, now the application is approved and up on the app-store.